# My Confluence server will not start after reboot - "Your database Storage Engine could not be determined"

Tags: mysql, confluence

I have had a confluence server for a while, and it recently ran out of space.  I added space and rebooted the server, and it will not start.  It displays an error "Your database Storage Engine could not be determined."

The server had not rebooted in a while.  Jira is installed on the same server, and that is working fine after the reboot.

I believe we are using am confluence version 6.15.2 (based on the readme file) and my MySQL driver is mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.

I am able to access MySQL from the CLI using mysql -h localhost --port=3306 -u confluence -pPASSWORD 'confluence' so I am using the correct port.

We followed the Confluence docs to reconfigure the confluence.cfg.xml file but still get the same error.

Any help on where the issue could be would be greatly appreciated!

Ken

Comment: Because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! - it was likely an issue with the /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema/ not being owned by mysql user, or that the mysql db needed to be upgraded.

1. renamed the confluence.cfg.xml file
2. when starting up, put in settings for the existing DB
3. tried to "test connection" received an error about writing to './performance_schema'  - realized MySQL was not the owner of the folder /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema/ - so I changed that and also changed the permissions
4. then received an error about 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist' an upgraded MySQL using mysql_upgrade
5. test connection was successful! hit next, and then it warned me there was an existing DB it was about to overwrite. Stopped, and went back and then just rebooted the server
6. I copied the old confluence.cfg.xml file back
7. rebooted the server, and it worked!